# How to remove only one hard wrap indicator in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, word-wrap, pep8

I am trying to get rid of the standard hard wrap indicator in pycharm while keeping the ones I added (the two leftmost):

[image]

I tried to use the setting und Editor/General/Appearence: Show hard wrap and visual guides[...]

But it removed my custom lines as well.

Also I have noticed that this standard line is not at 120 chars (how it should be configured) but at 97 chars:

[image]

How do I remove the standard line at 97 chars and keep my custom lines at 79 and 72 chars (which are the PEP Standards for line wrapping)